# Programmatically set ActionBarTab background color with tab selector line color at bottom with user chosen color in ActionBarTab?

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I want to change my ActionBar's Tabs background color with tabs selector line at bottom color.

I want to do that by using java code not xml.

I have tried creating ActionBar tabs ..

```
actionBar = getActionBar();


// Hide the action bar title
           ActionBar actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        // Enabling Spinner dropdown navigation
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

         ActionBar.Tab PlayerTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("Fragment A");
          ActionBar.Tab StationsTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("Fragment B");

          //create the two fragments we want to use for display content
         //////////////////////// Fragment PlayerFragment = new AFragment();
         /////////////////// Fragment StationsFragment = new BFragment();

          //set the Tab listener. Now we can listen for clicks.
          ///////////////////PlayerTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(PlayerFragment));
         ///////////////// ////StationsTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(StationsFragment));

          //add the two tabs to the actionbar
          actionBar.addTab(PlayerTab);
          actionBar.addTab(StationsTab);
```

Now when I try to set background color with tabs line selector color, I get the error `Java.lang.NullPointException`

My OnTabSelcted() method ..

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
RelativeLayout tabLayout = (RelativeLayout) tab.getCustomView();

//tab.setCustomView(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tabs_selector_blue));

     System.out.println("Tab position is " +tab.getPosition());
     try{
     if(tab.getCustomView() == null){

tabLayout.setBackgroundResource(TABS_BACKGROUND[tab.getPosition()]);
         tab.setCustomView(tabLayout);
     }else{
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "check for tabs", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
     }catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

}
```

I have defined a custom selector for background and need to inflate it.

I am getting on line `tabLayout.setBackgroundResource(TABS_BACKGROUND[tab.getPosition()]);`

Please let show me where's my error.

Comment: did you initialize `TABS_BACKGROUND` array?

Comment: Yes I did .. private static final int[] TABS_BACKGROUND = {
        R.drawable.tabs_selector_blue, R.drawable.tabs_selector_blue,
        R.drawable.tabs_selector_blue};

Comment: so `tabLayout` is null, see Gopal answer

Comment: yes my tabLayout is null

Answer (score 2):

I see you are using [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486571/is-it-possible-to-change-actionbar-tab-indicator-programmatically/18491600#18491600). Your `tabLayout` may be null if you didn't initialise it when creating tabs. Here is the code I used to create tabs first, before changing background and text color in `onTabSelected`

```
for (int i = 0; i < TABS.length; i++) {
    Tab tab = actionBar.newTab();
    tab.setText(TABS[i]);
    tab.setTabListener(this);
    tab.setCustomView(getTabView(i));  << see getTabView() method below  
    actionBar.addTab(tab, i, (currentTab == i));
}
```

getTabView() method :

```
private View getTabView(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    RelativeLayout r = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    TextView t = (TextView) r.findViewById(R.id.custom_tab_text);
    t.setText(TABS[i]);
    int color;
    switch (i) {
    case MyObject.TYPE_A:
        color = MyObject.COLOR_A;
        break;
    case MyObject.TYPE_B:
        color = MyObject.B;
        break;
    case MyObject.TYPE_C:
        color = MyObject.COLOR_C;
        break;
    case MyObject.TYPE_E:
        color = MyObject.COLOR_E;
        break;
    case MyObject.TYPE_F:
        color = MyObject.COLOR_F;
        break;
    default:
        color = MyObject.COLOR_A;
        break;
    }

    t.setTextColor(color);
    return r;
}
```

Finally, `custom_tab.xml`, the layout of tabs:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/custom_tab_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

see the statement

```
RelativeLayout tabLayout = (RelativeLayout) tab.getCustomView();
```

and `if` condition

```
if(tab.getCustomView() == null){
     tabLayout.setBackgroundResource(TABS_BACKGROUND[tab.getPosition()]);
     tab.setCustomView(tabLayout);
}
```

Now, if `tab.getCustomView()` returns `null`, then `tabLayout` is also `null` and the `if` condition becomes `true`. and inside `if` condition, you are referencing `tabLayout` which is `null`...

Comment: I have initialized same as .. RelativeLayout tabLayout = (RelativeLayout) tab.getCustomView();. Did I need to do something else?

Comment: already `tab.getCustomView()` is returning `null`. then how can you say that it is initialized? assign `tabLayout` to a `View` which you want...

Comment: @AndroidHacker, check my answer. You didn't initialised the tab custom view as Gopal Rao said. That's why you are getting NPE.