# Change the color of the selected TabItem footer

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, android-tabs, android-tabstrip

I cannot change the color of the bottom of the selected tab (`TabItem`) on the `TabControl`. I need to change from light blue to dark blue as at the top.

I'm using Firemonkey for Android and Delphi XE6.

[image]

Comment: Use CustomTab and Tab selector for your purpose
You can refer [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486571/is-it-possible-to-change-actionbar-tab-indicator-programmatically

Answer (score 3):

1. Open **Bitmap Style Designer** (see a bin folder of IDE Rad Studio)
2. In Menu: **File -> New -> Android Light Style for FireMonkey** (or Dark style)
3. Expand node **"Images"**. There are a several images for different screen scales.
4. Look at the **style.png**. Find a subimages for Tab. Tou can repaint this area. Don't forget, that you need to do it for all images (for all screen scales: **style15**, **style20**, **style30**)
5. Save style to file.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Styles:

use the following link to help you obtain original default style.From there you can use a copy of the style, and make changes as you wish via dropping a TStylebook and double clicking-> Loading your copied style -> after you make changes, then save and apply.. Then simply change the stylebook property for the form...

http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2013/12/31/inspecting-platform-styles-redux/

Answer (score 0):

May be [theme generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=appcompat&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&texture=0&hairline=0&neutralPressed=1&backColor=E4E4E4%2C100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6%2C100&tabColor=253b44%2C100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2%2C100&accentColor=33B5E5%2C100&cabBackColor=FFFFFF%2C100&cabHighlightColor=33B5E5%2C100)     will help you.

Change the style name [now example] and Set your theme, and Just download the zip, paste it in your resource folder, then change the theme in your manifest file, like

```
android:theme="@style/example"
```

I hope this will help you.