# How to change the selected tab indicator color programatically in Action Bar Tabs

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I have list view and each list item holds different color. On click of any list item, I navigate to an activity whose action bar holds some tabs. Now I have to set that color which came from item click as tab indicator color of selected tab. I tried the below link but no luck

[Is it possible to change actionbar tab indicator programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486571/is-it-possible-to-change-actionbar-tab-indicator-programmatically)

Comment: that should work .. what have you done so far ??

Answer (score 1):

you can change focus of selected tab

```
<!-- Non focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false"
      android:state_pressed="false"
      android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"
      android:state_pressed="false"
      android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected" />

<!-- Focused states (such as when focused with a d-pad or mouse hover) -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false"
      android:state_pressed="false"
      android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_focused" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"
      android:state_pressed="false"
      android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_focused" />
```

```
<!-- Non focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false"
      android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed" />

<!-- Focused states (such as when focused with a d-pad or mouse hover) -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false"
      android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"
      android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed" />
```

For more details go through [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomTabs)